# Join workstation to domain, short domain name or FQDN?

Tags: domain-name

Bit of a sanity check required if you don't mind.

When joining a Windows 8 machine to the domain should we use the short domain name 'domain' or the FQDN domain.local?

I seem to recall that I have always used domain.local but wonder if this is still ok with windows 8?

Reason for asking is that we are seeing various Server 2012 issues and from some of the diagnostic logs I am beginning to wonder if using domain.local is correct.

Comment: Using `.local` in your domain name is never correct. But that might be an issue for another day...

Comment: Habit, been calling all Windows domains xxx.local for the past twenty years (since NT4 server).  My personal opinion is that allocating .local to bonjour traffic was a pretty stupid decision in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NETBIOS name and FQDN will work, I'd imagine FQDN would be the "better" way of doing it, but they both use the same mechanism after it gets the IPs of the domain controllers.

Comment: Unless of course you are one of those brave souls that have actually disabled NETBIOS, in which case, that won't work at all and only the FQDN will work.

Comment: Just tested and if we enter the short NETBIOS name, after the workstation reboots it automatically gets converted to the FQDN anyway.